# external hard drive not detected UBUNTU 12.10

Tags: 12.10, usb, hard-drive, detect

My 1 TB external hard disk is not detected by Ubuntu 12.10.

```
**lsusb:**

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6409 Microdia Webcam
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c03d Logitech, Inc. M-BT96a Pilot Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c315 Logitech, Inc. Classic New Touch Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 059b:0070 Iomega Corp. 



**sudo fdisk -l:**

Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250263728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0006ec0d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048  1242566655   621282304   83  Linux
/dev/sda2      1242568702  1250263039     3847169    5  Extended
/dev/sda5      1242568704  1250263039     3847168   82  Linux swap / Solaris




**sudo blkid:**

/dev/sda1: UUID="9d449e79-8917-497f-aa4c-59fb3bcb21ee" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="ea2d407e-0b84-4d6e-9004-5b3536a899fd" TYPE="swap"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is the Hard Disk formatted with an MBR? some stock hard disks require formatting for use, but either way the driver should have been installed. if the disk came with a CD, use the cd to install the validation drivers. If it didnt, you may have a defective disk, or your memory controller is malfunctioning (most likely not but its still a scenerio). check with the manufacturer of your computer (Dell, HP, PowerPC ect) and ask for specs concerning how much physical memory the system can handle. Basic run through, check your device ports and drivers (and if the HDD has a power supply, make sure its plugged in).
references: I repair computer hardware and program software for over 8 years
Hope this helped you :)

Answer (score -1):

Run in terminal:

```
dmesg
```

this will display the kernel messages, in my case I was having a problem with my hub:

```
hub_port_status failed (err = -110)
```

I connected directly and it worked like a charm.

Cheers!

Comment: Why was this downvoted?